# Android RxJava 2, subscribeOn with BehaviorSubject stay on MainThread

Tags: android, rx-java2

I'm using a BehaviourSubject with RxJava2 in Android. In this following chain I receive an NetworkOnMainThreadException even if I subscribeOn(schedulers.background()).

If I use ObserveOn(schedulers.background()) just after the searchRequestSubject, I correctly go in a background thread.

I expect that using subscribeOn will get all the chain into the provided thread? Why it's not working this way?

`private BehaviorSubject<SearchRequest> searchRequestSubject = BehaviorSubject.create();`

```
searchRequestSubject
            .doOnEach(responseNotification -> Logger.d("Current Thread1: "+Thread.currentThread()))
//.observeOn(schedulers.background()) // this is the current solution but
            .flatMap(searchRequest -> adSearchService.getAds(searchRequest))
            .doOnEach(responseNotification -> Logger.d("Current Thread2: "+Thread.currentThread()))
            .doOnNext(apiResponse -> updateResponseSubject(apiResponse))
            .doOnEach(responseNotification -> Logger.d("Current Thread3: "+Thread.currentThread()))
            .subscribeOn(schedulers.background()) // this one should make the whole chain to subscribe on background. but it don't. why?
            .subscribe()

// Logs //
Current Thread1: Thread[main,5,main]
Current Thread2: Thread[main,5,main]
Current Thread3: Thread[main,5,main]
```

Network Call

```
public Observable<ApiResponse> getAds(@NonNull SearchRequest adRequest){
    if (adRequest == null){
        throw new IllegalStateException("Search Request should never be null");
    }

    return apiService.getAdsObservable(token, adRequest.pageNumber(), adRequest.resultsNumberByPage(), adRequest.presentation(),
            adRequest.toLatLongQuery(), adRequest.isClosed(), adRequest.toAdTypeQuery(), adRequest.category(),
            adRequest.keywords(),adRequest.radius(), adRequest.from(), adRequest.to(), adRequest.isReserved(), adRequest.adId())
        .map(response -> handleResponseCode(response, adRequest.location()))
        .onErrorReturn(error -> errorHandling.handleError(error));
}

private ApiResponse handleResponseCode(Response<AdResponse> response, Location location) {
    if (response.isSuccessful()){
        return AdSearchResponse.Response.create(response.body(), location);
    } else if (response.code() == 404){
        return AdSearchResponse.NotFoundError.create();
    } else {
        return errorHandling.handleError(response, null);
    }
}
```

ApiService is provided by Retrofit 2

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class AppSchedulers {
    public abstract Scheduler UI(); // AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()
    public abstract Scheduler background(); // Schedulers.io()
    // [...] creator and builder
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with not `subscribe()` but with other sibling that takes parameter?

Comment: Yes, I've removed the data in the subscribe for the clarity

Comment: As said in my (deleted) answer, your code works for me. So there should be something wrong in your network request, I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rage, frustration, and unit tests that shows that it's not due to a hot / cold observable problem. I've cleaned the build. Restarted Android Studio. Build again and it was working as expected without any changes.

Always Clean/Rebuild when any doubt...

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's because you are using a hot observable (BehaviorSubject) and unless you are using an observeOn you will stay on the thread that did the onNext. subscribeOn will most of the time be use for cold observables. So in your case :

```
searchRequestSubject
    .observeOn(schedulers.background())
    .doOnEach(responseNotification -> Logger.d("Current Thread1: "+Thread.currentThread()))
    .flatMap(searchRequest -> adSearchService.getAds(searchRequest))
    .doOnEach(responseNotification -> Logger.d("Current Thread2: "+Thread.currentThread()))
    .doOnNext(apiResponse -> updateResponseSubject(apiResponse))
    .doOnEach(responseNotification -> Logger.d("Current Thread3: "+Thread.currentThread()))
    .subscribe()
```

Check that link, go to the ObserveOn section : http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.ca/2016/02/rxjava-understanding-observeon-and.html
Your onNext is like a click action